# заголовки браузера

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest

что означает вот эта запись в заголовках которые браузер отправляет с другими заголовками

```
Accept: */*
```

Comment: А в гугле не быстрее забить, чем тут вопрос создавать?)

Answer (score 2):

Браузер сообщает серверу о том, что он всё готов принять в его ответе.

[Список заголовков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_HTTP) на Википедии.